# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\arctan (x^2)\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, error-function

How to evaluate
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\arctan (x^2)\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx$$
with the help of Wolfram alpha,I got the answer below
$$I=\frac{\pi^{2/3}\text{erfc(1)}(\text{erfi(1)}+1)}{4\sqrt2}$$
But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I am ready to bet that this involves the Dawson integral. But, how to prove it, this is the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach is to use differentiation under the integral sign. If we set:
$$ I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\arctan(\alpha x^2)\sin(x^2)\,dx $$
for any $\alpha> 0$, we have:
$$ I'(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+a^2 x^4}\,\sin(x^2)\,dx $$
that can be computed trough the Laplace transform:
$$ I'(\alpha) = \frac{\pi e^{-1/\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2\pi^3}}\left(\text{Erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)-e^{2/\alpha}\text{Erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)\right) $$
and by:
$$ I(1)=\int_{0}^{1}I'(\alpha)\,d\alpha $$
the claim follows.